# Dividing the world space to geographic sub-space

Tags: cartography, topology, generalization, area, geolocation

I am trying to divide the world space to geographic sub-space from "general" to "specific" locations and without using latitude and longitude information. That is, I am trying to think about the world in someway like the following:

```
The most "general sub-space" > ... > The most "specific sub-space"
```

*Example*

```
Continent > State > Region > ... > City > Town > Address
```

1. What is (are) the most *used* "division approach(es)"?
2. What is (are) the most *efficient* "division approach(es)"?

Comment: "To what end" ... would go a long way to assisting in a reasoned answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a problem that everyone solves with a slight difference. IMHO, Yahoo did a great job with [WOEIDs](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/concepts.html).

As far as what is the most *efficient* way, it seems the answer is too subjective and dependent on your application.